# Why did Peeta suggest that they wait Katniss out?

Tags: the-hunger-games

In the movie *Hunger Games* when the gang was chasing Katniss and she climbed a tree they started shooting at her. However, Peeta suggested that they wait for her to get down, why would he do that if he liked her?

Comment: To prevent her immediate death...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this to be one of the many huge mistakes in the movie (I haven't read the book). Waiting under the tree until she either gets tired and falls off, or gets desperate and tries to make a run for it. 
It's almost understandable, but camping under that tree was plain dumb.

Even if there wasn't something

> a wasps or hornets nest

In that tree for her to throw down, she had a knife and could have flung that down at anyone sleeping below her tree. Or she could have sharpened a branch and flung that down.

The [Rule of Three](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/is-the-rule-of-3-proven-for-food) suggests she could have gone three days up there without fluid (assuming it didn't rain).

Why Peeta suggested they should wait her out, is a good question. (the answer is he liked her and wanted to give her a chance that didn't involve arrows) It's the: why did they just went a long with it that is mind boggling. They had options like continue shooting arrows at her (if they really wanted her dead), or moving on to hunt someone else or curse at her, shake their fists, then walk of, only to hide and wait out of sight for her to come down.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative was to watch her be killed right then and there. Also, bear in mind that while Peeta has a thing for Katniss, like most human beings, he has a thing for preserving his own life first. I'd push everyone except my wife and daughters under a bus if it saved my own life, and I'm a grown man, not a teenager. The instant he stops being useful to the gang, they will turn on him; this actually happens in the film, though we don't see it. Sacrificing Katniss helps preserve his own life, and saying to wait her out has the possibility to preserve hers. It's a win-win from his viewpoint.

Comment: I understand that, but looking how they shoot (I'm an archer myself) they won't hit her, Peeta just gives them an idea which is great since she can't do anything about it. It's sad how people would save themselves instead of protecting their loved ones

Comment: @user36610: As an archer, you are probably a lot more knowledgeable than Hollywood wants n audience is meant to be.

Comment: @user36610 "looking how they shoot (I'm an archer myself) they won't hit her" << so could he be preserving the arrows for Katniss? Probably much harder to retrieve if they're all shot into the trees, but if they're in the quiver then they're easy to steal later.

Comment: could be - convincing the group to wait - he stops them from thinking of other ways to bring Katniss down (that might succeed). It buys Katniss (and Peeta) time to think calmly of a way out. Also Peeta is exploiting a basic human weakness of the group laziness. Probably also part of Careers training "dont expend too much energy in killing opponents"

Comment: @JamesSheridan I'm never standing next to you at a bus stop.

Answer (score 2):

Peeta told them to wait, because it was the logical decision to make them lay off fighting her and make himself seem useful. From the book he was just trying to survive and since he wasn't huge like Thresh, couldn't hide in trees like Rue and Katniss and wasn't sly like Foxface, he needed allies.

[From the Wikia:](http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/Peeta_Mellark)

> They find Katniss and chase her up a tree, with Peeta suggesting that
>   they make camp under it, as none of them are able to climb after her.
>   In the morning, they wake up to a tracker jacker attack after Katniss
>   unleashes a nest of them.

He was giving her time to figure it out, because he knew that he couldn't stop them and they would both be killed.

**He wasn't trying to save himself.**

> Peeta finds Katniss at the scene of the attack as she is removing the
>   bow and arrows from Glimmer's body, and he urges her to run due to
>   Cato's impending attempt to kill her. Cato witnesses this exchange and
>   cuts Peeta in his upper thigh for his actions, severely wounding him,
>   then relegating him from the Career pack.

He risked it all for her, after he couldn't hide his true intentions anymore. He could have killed her there(or attempted to) and they would have trusted him a lot them. But instead he risks his life for her.

### He saves her for several reasons:

- He had a crush on her

**It was not as simple as he wanted to save her.**

- He was trying to seem helpful so that they didn't kill him. They knew that if was in "love" with her, if he tried to save her and seemed even less likely to want to kill her they would have instantly chose him for the next target. But appearing to throw her under the bush gave him a reprieve.

Also, it was part of a plan to save Katniss he was helping her and simultaneously helping himself by saving her(so he had a ally) and so that they both got more sponsors.